# Why is my default value not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My default value for MOVIE_RATING doesn't seem to work. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my query or help me fix it. Thank you very much.

```
Create table MOVIE
(
    MOVIE_ID int(7) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    MOVIE_NAME Varchar(20),
    MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE date,
    MOVIE_RATING Varchar(5) DEFAULT 'NR',
    CHECK (MOVIE_RATING = 'G'OR MOVIE_RATING = 'PG' OR MOVIE_RATING = 
    'PG-13' OR MOVIE_RATING = 
    'R' OR MOVIE_RATING = 'NC'),
    primary key (MOVIE_ID)
);
```

Comment: _"Doesn't seem to work"_ is not a problem description. Describe what you expect to happen, and what actually happens, and include the complete text of any error messages you see

Comment: The problem is that you don´t have a DEFAULT value for a primarykey, set a default value (maybe autoincrement) and you will solve it

Answer (score 0):

@Zolan Noir you not check for Move Rating when value Is 'NR'. So if you want to use default value of course it Will trigger error because you already defined a constrain CHECK for movie rating field but when check it there Is no 'NR' value on CHECK constrain.

NB: CHECK Will build a constrain while on your CHECK constrain there Is no check for a value "NR" on field Movie Rating. Except you don't add a CHECK on movie rating the code your write Will all right.

Oh one last thing please remove not null and UNIQUE constrain on movie id because you define that field as a Primary Key. There Is no use that because a Primary Key Will build a index constrain with characteristics similar as unique and not null.

Answer (score -2):

You didn't check the DEFAULT value for rating

add this on CHECK OR MOVIE_RATING = 'NR'

Comment: You can't insert data with the default value for MOVIE_RATING when on CHECK there is no CHECK for DEFAULT value it self

Comment: BTW what using UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY for the same field? PK it self has create an index similar to UNIQUE